# How to redirect to login page when user refresh or press f5 in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I want user to navigate if they refresh current page. I tried something like this,

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.location.href = 'url';
  }
</script>
```

but this does not worked.Is there any other way to do it? please help me in this.

appcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from 
'@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: @AJT_82 will you please explain more, I am completely new to angular. I edited my code and added my app component.

Comment: Awesome man @AJT_82..thank you :)

Comment: put your routing file here